# OpenCV: Program craches when address-operator is used to change a pixel

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, crash

I wrote a function, that does some calculations on a pixel.

```
Mat someCalc(Mat img) {
  double min, max;
  minMaxLoc(img, &min, &max);
  
  double conRangeMin = 100;
  double conRangeMax = 150;

  Mat processed = img.clone();

  for (int y = 0; y < processed.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < processed.cols; x++) {
      double& pixel = processed.at<double>(y, x));
      pixel = (pixel - conRangeMin) * ((max - min) / (conRangeMax - conRangeMin));
    }
  }
return processed;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

The program crashes with the  error code "-1073740940" and I noticed that if I remove the adress operator for the `pixel` variable, the error disappears. The same error happens when I change the pixel directly, like `processed.at<double>(y, x) = ...`

I am passing a grayscale image to the function.

The pixel isn't being changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The shown code does not compile due to `(`/`)` mismatch. Please make sure that you copy-paste code that you actually tested.

Comment: "_adress operator for the pixel variable_": That is not the address-of operator. It is a reference.

Comment: Is img really 64 bit double pixel type (CV_64FC1)? if not you will to convert it first by .convertTo

Comment: @Micka that should be the problem. Its a grayscale image. Do you have tips on how I can change/manipulate a single channel (grayscale) image?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to know the type for the pixel in the image, then use that type in the `at<>()` call.

Comment: Yes, you need to know the type, otherwise you will access wrong data. If you used default parameters to load the image, the type will be CV_8UC3 (cv::Vec3b), even for a grayscale image! Check the img.type() method!